# context.savechanges loses value and errors out

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am trying to add and save a user's settings for my application by the following code:

```
 SettingsPreference order = _context.SettingsPreference.SingleOrDefault(x => x.employeeNumber == settingsOrder.employeeNumber);

 if (order != null)
 {
    _context.Entry(order).CurrentValues.SetValues(settingsOrder);
 }
 else
 {
    _context.SettingsPreference.Add(settingsOrder);

 }

 _context.SaveChanges();
```

My SettingsPreference object contains an int of employeeNumber and and a string of viewOrder. As I step through the method while debugging it, it holds the values of employeeNumber = 9999 and viewOrder = "randomString" throughout the whole method until it gets to SaveChanges. When it tries to execute the save after trying to add it to a database, it errors out and gives the exception of trying to add a null int into employeeNumber when I know its not null going in. The SaveChanges works when updating a value in the database, but when I try to add a new one, SaveChanges() loses my employeeNumber.

Here is my object class:

```
public partial class SettingsPreference
{
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 0)]
    public int employeeNumber { get; set; }
    public string viewOrder { get; set; }

}
```

What or why is it losing the value and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Without further notice, EF will consider `int` primary keys as identity columns. Which means, it doesn't insert a value for it, on the contrary, it reads the generated value from the database after the insert.

You must tell EF explicitly that the key is not database-generated:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
...

public partial class SettingsPreference
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int employeeNumber { get; set; }
    public string viewOrder { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: thank you, that worked. any idea as to why very similar code works at another area in my code? did i just get lucky?

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing it. Perhaps the column actually was an identity column there.